# How to reverse an AAC audio file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, aac

I am currently able to record and playback in reverse (thanks to a couple examples), but I would like to give the user the ability to select a previously recorded .AAC file from a table view and reverse it. 
I have tried changing the input file url to the url of the user's file, but I either get static or an audio file with 0.0 duration. Is this type of reversal possible with AAC files? If so, how do I correct my settings to accept it?

```
recordedAudioUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[savedURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog( @"url is %@", [recordedAudioUrl absoluteString]);

flippedAudioUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[reverseURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog( @"url is %@", [flippedAudioUrl absoluteString]);

AudioFileID outputAudioFile;

AudioStreamBasicDescription myPCMFormat;
myPCMFormat.mSampleRate = 16000.00;
myPCMFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM ;
myPCMFormat.mFormatFlags =  kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical;
myPCMFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
myPCMFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
myPCMFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
myPCMFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2;
myPCMFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2;

AudioFileCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)flippedAudioUrl,
                       kAudioFileCAFType,
                       &myPCMFormat,
                       kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
                       &outputAudioFile);

AudioFileID inputAudioFile;
OSStatus theErr = noErr;
UInt64 fileDataSize = 0;

AudioStreamBasicDescription theFileFormat;
UInt32 thePropertySize = sizeof(theFileFormat);

theErr = AudioFileOpenURL((__bridge CFURLRef)recordedAudioUrl, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &inputAudioFile);

thePropertySize = sizeof(fileDataSize);
theErr = AudioFileGetProperty(inputAudioFile, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataByteCount, &thePropertySize, &fileDataSize);

UInt32 dataSize = fileDataSize;
void* theData = malloc(dataSize);

//Read data into buffer
SInt64 readPoint  = dataSize;
UInt32 writePoint = 0;
while( readPoint > 0 )
{
    UInt32 bytesToRead = 2;
    AudioFileReadBytes( inputAudioFile, false, readPoint, &bytesToRead, theData );
    AudioFileWriteBytes( outputAudioFile, false, writePoint, &bytesToRead, theData );

    writePoint += 2;
    readPoint -= 2;
}

free(theData);
AudioFileClose(inputAudioFile);
AudioFileClose(outputAudioFile);

}
```

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do, could you add more info? "Record the recording"?

Comment: The user records audio file which is saved in the .AAC format. The .AAC files are accessible from a tableview, where they can select one then reverse it.

Comment: Do you need to save it as reversed.aac? Or just play it back?

Comment: @Danijel yes, I would like to have a reversed .aac saved. If that is a separate issue, I can work on that when I get there.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is reading raw AAC data backwards (`AudioFileReadBytes` doesn't even respect packet boundaries, unlike `AudioFileReadPacketData`), and then writing it forwards as LPCM. No wonder you're hearing static. To reverse an AAC file you will have to decode it to LPCM first. I suggest you switch your reading code from `AudioFile` to either `ExtendedAudioFile` or `AVAudioFile`.

Your read-backwards-and-write-forwards approach should still work with the above change.

The APIs mentioned can decode AAC (among other things) to LPCM, e.g. 
[decoding with AVAudioFile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34759136/22147) and [decoding with ExtAudioFile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20337974/22147)

**NB** the examples aren't reading AAC, but that doesn't matter as the APIs hide the details from you so your code doesn't need to care what the source format is.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive reply! Would you mind attaching an example on decoding an AAC file to LPCM? I am new to Objective-C and having trouble finding an example.

Comment: I added some examples. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

1. decode your whole input file to PCM
2. reverse decoded PCM samples
3. encode reversed PCM samples to AAC and save

This will give you reversed.aac.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Could you provide a bit of sample code to get me on the right track? I am very new to Objective-C and having trouble finding decoding tutorials.